# spring-boot にて、定時実行バッチを記述したい

Tags: java, spring-boot

spring-boot でバックエンドのサービスを開発しています。

以下の性質を持つバッチ群を作成したいと考えているのですが、spring 的に、どのような構成でバッチを作成するのが正しいのか、わからずにいます。

- 各バッチは、 DataManager Bean (インスタンス) を共通して使いたい.
  (排他制御は DataManager が行う)
- 各バッチは、それぞれ非同期実行してもかまわない
- 各バッチは、それぞれに定められた周期で定期的に実行される。

自分でパッと考えつくのは、

- 各バッチごとに、 XxxBatchManager を Bean で作成
- 各 BatchManager は、バッチジョブを実行し、それが終わったら sleep(規定時間) を行う。これを繰り返す。

なのですが、もうちょっとうまい方法があるのではないか、と思い質問しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

に、一通り可能なオプションが記述されていました。今回のケースでは、 `@Scheduled` オプションが、最もほしいものに近いです。指定されたメソッドを、 spring boot が用意してくれる Executor で、指定頻度で実行してくれます。

XxxBatch.java

```
@Component
public class XxxxBatch {

    @Autowired
    private DataManager dataManager;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = rateInMilliSeconds)
    public void doBatchJob() {
        // 略
    }
}
```

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
// Configuration に下記アノテーションを付与することで、
// @Scheduled が使えるようになる。
@EnableScheduling
public AppConfig {
    // もろもろの config
}
```